# Import Certificates from Firefox's trust store

Tags: java, firefox, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

In general, is it possible to import the list of certificates that already comes in the Firefox's trust store (also called Certificate Manager) using JAVA?

Comment: Java keytool will probably be able to extract the certificates from the Firefox trust store, and will certainly be able to import them into a store that a java application can use, if that's what you're asking.  Your Java JRE should include a copy of keytool.

Comment: Mozilla certificate storage can be accessed via PKCS#11 interface (and this one is supported in Java).

Answer (score 0):

You still need to export certificates to PEM/PKCS format before processing it with keytool.

Firefox uses it's own internal certificate storage (not system one like Chome) so there is another 'theoretically' possible solution: native calls to Firefox libraries through JNA.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435836/access-firefoxs-certificate-trust-store-from-java). It uses [JSS library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSS) which is an interface to firefox nss.